# orjson and json dumps method not the same python3.8

Tags: json, python-3.x, orjson

I have switched to orjson since it is faster, but this has caused an issue I have had for a fair amount of time now but never thought anything of it. I finally decided to do tests and these were my tests.

```
import orjson, json


data = json.dumps({"channel_id" : None, "payment_source_id" : None})
print(data)

data = orjson.dumps({"channel_id" : None, "payment_source_id" : None}).decode("utf-8")
print(data)

{"channel_id": null, "payment_source_id": null}
{"channel_id":null,"payment_source_id":null}
```

This is my testing file. When you run this you see that the only difference is the space between null and the quotes. When I try to dump json data using orjson and send it in a request , I get a 400 bad request and sometimes nothing back at all, but when trying with the json lib everything works fine, I get a valid response back. I’m not sure what to do because like I said the only difference is the spaces. Has anyone had a similar issue and can tell me what’s happening or what Im doing wrong? Also another thing to note is that if there is no “None” in my code orjson works fine.

Comment: Both of those strings are perfectly valid JSON.  If the receiving end doesn't work with one, I'd have to say it has a broken JSON parser.

Comment: i doubt this since its discord

Comment: space has no effect on JavaScript and JSON. The space only has effect on beautifying or minifying of JS/JSON

Answer (score 8):

*orjson* saves a few bytes (whitespaces after separators) by emitting **`:`** instead of **`:`**  and **`,`** instead of **`,`**  as the native *json* module does by default.

The native *json* module has an option to change this behavior with the *separators* argument, while *orjson* does not.

In my opinion, unless you are testing the correctness of what any json modules produce, and *should* already exist in a test suite of the module you use written by their authors, I would probably not test by asserting the byte/string outputs. Instead - as previous comments hint - assert all/parts of the python object contents after converting it from json. Any json module in your test will fail anyways if it can't deserialize/loads.

(Note: *orjson* produces *bytes* while *json* produces *str*ings.)

```
>>> import orjson
>>> import json
>>> orjson.dumps({"hello":"world"})
b'{"hello":"world"}'
>>> json.dumps({"hello":"world"})
'{"hello": "world"}'
>>>
>>> type(orjson.dumps({"hello":"world"}))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> type(json.dumps({"hello":"world"}))
<class 'str'>
```

```
>>> json.dumps({"hello":"world"}, separators=(',', ':'))
'{"hello":"world"}'
>>> orjson.dumps({"hello":"world"}, separators=(',', ':'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: dumps() got an unexpected keyword argument
```

Answer (score 7):

I think there isn't any difference. please check this:

```
import orjson, json

data1 = json.dumps({"channel_id" : None, "payment_source_id" : None})
data2 = orjson.dumps({"channel_id" : None, "payment_source_id" : None}).decode("utf-8")

print(json.loads(data2))
print (orjson.loads(data1))

{'channel_id': None, 'payment_source_id': None}
{'channel_id': None, 'payment_source_id': None}
```

The space difference is for just string. If you load to json, the result will be same.
You can get success if you convert string to json while your api calling.